# To join or not to join, database structuring

Tags: mysql, join, database-design

I'm trying to construct a database that will do the following:

"Allow a user to give or take a number of items from another user and leave an optional comment about it."

I would think this only would need two tables:

**Users Table:**

UserID (PK)
FirstName
LastName
Email
Password
ItemBalance
DateCreated
DateModified

**Transactions Table:**

TxnID (PK)
NumOfItems
GiveTake
ToUser (FK)
FromUser (FK)
Comment
DateCreated
DateModified

Would this do the trick or should I have a join table? I can see where Transactions could have many users so it seems like it could be a many-to-many relationship. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: if you really have a many to many then you do need an intermediate table.

Comment: So users have infinite quantities of items?

Answer (score 0):

The current requirement you listed only allows transactions between two users - the `ToUser` and `FromUser` in your current table. So for this usecase, your design is fine.

Comment: A user can give or take an item from several users but it will always be an individual transaction between the two users, so I believe this still stands. Thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

I would leave the users table alone and create the transaction table separate like you suggest in your question.
This will help you to keep track on all the transaction.

if you join the tables you will have either too much of the same data or your will have only the last transaction.